# Google Maps API Shadow/Filter Points by X minutes by Walk/Bus/Drive

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm open for a better title. Unfortunately my English is not good enough.

Below url is a Google Hotels page. There is a map at right which highlights the points in 5 mins driving distance. Able to change type to public transport and walking.

I couldn't find which API methods are involved. How to filter out points and how to black out map.

https://www.google.com/hotels/#search;l=Manchester,+United+Kingdom;d=2014-03-18;n=3;usd=1;mf=r;ar=;rtt=300;si=5b02088;av=r